# Windows Command Prompt -- find a file that contains "main" in its name and push that file onto an Android device

Tags: windows, search, cmd.exe

Is it possible to use Command Prompt to locate a file in the directory that contains the word "main" in its name and then push that file onto an Android device?

This is what I have so far -

```
pushd \\nm\games\BeaverGames\Mobile\Custom Street Racer\Builds\GooglePlay 
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /a:d *2015*') do cd %a
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /a:d *10*') do cd %a
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /a:d *prod*') do cd %a
adb push csr.apk /sdcard/.
adb shell mkdir /sdcard/Android/obb/com.naturalmotion.csrracing
```

This gets me to a point where I have 2 files in a folder that I need to push onto an Android device, one called `main 1001` and one called `patch 1001`.
Now the numbers in the file name always change but the word "main" and "patch" do not.
So is it possible to search for just the word "main" and then push it onto the device?

Comment: It is possible but you will need to show effort was shown in your question before anyone helps you.  Nobody will want to do all of the work for you.

Comment: I don't even know what your asking.

Comment: ah ok thanks for the heads up. I have tried loads of things and they are most probably all wrong. But I will post them anyways.

Comment: Sorry if it is unclear. I have updated my question hope it helps

Comment: Take a look here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010253/dos-find-a-string-if-found-then-run-another-script

Comment: Since you seem to be unsure about the searching for the word "Main", that answer seems to get at what you need. Just combine it with your adb commands.

Comment: I'm sorry but even after looking at the link you provided I was still unable to figure it out.

Comment: Use the link I provided to find the files containing "main" then transfer them using your method.

Comment: I have tried - find . -name "*main*" and got file not found

Comment: Can you just pass an argument of `*main*` to your command?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for a `.bat` script which browses your partial folder structure:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
pushd \\nm\games\BeaverGames\Mobile\Custom Street Racer\Builds\GooglePlay 

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%G in ('dir /b /a:d *2015*') do (
  pushd %%~fG
  echo folder G %%~fG

  for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%H in ('dir /b /a:d *10*') do (
    pushd %%~fH
    echo folder H %%~fH

    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a:d *prod*') do (
      pushd %%~fI
      echo folder I %%~fI

      for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%J in ('dir /b /a:-d *main*') do (
        echo file J %%~fJ

      ) 
      popd
    )
    popd
  )
  popd
)

popd
goto :eof
```

In place of (or next to) each `echo folder ...` (`echo file ...`) there could be a good position for next actions...